# Expand/collapse section in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, object

Could somebody tell me the way to perform `UITableView` expandable/collapsible animations in `sections` of `UITableView` as below?

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186659/how-to-create-drop-down-list-in-uitableview-in-ios

Comment: [Check out my answer to same for custom header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203434/uitableview-with-open-closed-sections/40932319#40932319)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203434/uitableview-with-open-closed-sections/40932319#40932319

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have to make your own custom header row and put that as the first row of each section. Subclassing the `UITableView` or the headers that are already there will be a pain. Based on the way they work now, I am not sure you can easily get actions out of them. You could set up a cell to LOOK like a header, and setup the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to manually expand or collapse the section it is in.

I'd store an array of booleans corresponding the the "expended" value of each of your sections. Then you could have the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on each of your custom header rows toggle this value and then reload that specific section.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        ///it's the first row of any section so it would be your custom section header

        ///put in your code to toggle your boolean value here
        mybooleans[indexPath.section] = !mybooleans[indexPath.section];

        ///reload this section
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Then set `numberOfRowsInSection` to check the `mybooleans` value and return 1 if the section isn't expanded, or 1+ the number of items in the section if it is expanded.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (mybooleans[section]) {
        ///we want the number of people plus the header cell
        return [self numberOfPeopleInGroup:section] + 1;
    } else {
        ///we just want the header cell
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Also, you will need to update `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to return a custom header cell for the first row in any section.

Comment: if you have used the Beejive app, you would know that their collapsible section header actually "float" at the top of the table even when you've scrolled through part of its section, just like the regular Apple section headers. that's not possible if you simply add a cell at the beginning of the section

Comment: Nice elegant solution!  user102008 has a point on the floating header, but in the scenario where you actually want the "sections" to scroll, this is a great approach.

Comment: @mjdth plz give me any sample code bcz i need a specific cell hide/unhide ..thanks in advance

Comment: `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` is the better way to provide your "own custom header", as that's exactly what it's designed to do.

Comment: this initially worked for me when i had just one section, but as soon as i had more, i get the "invalid update invalid number of rows" error. i know this solution is older, but will this only work for one section? if we have more than one section, will we need to add the code that actually adds/deletes the rows??

Comment: This may have been a good solution in the past, but it's now certainly better to simply subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and keep track of the data with indexes.

Answer (score 103):

Some sample code for animating an expand/collapse action using a table view section header is provided by Apple here: [Table View Animations and Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

The key to this approach is to implement `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and return a custom UIView which includes a button (typically the same size as the header view itself). By subclassing UIView and using that for the header view (as this sample does), you can easily store additional data such as the section number.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: dont remember, but why is the sample code not working on pre-iOS 4?

Comment: i don't know. it just says "iOS 4.0.2 or later"

Comment: @user102008 it probably wont work pre iOS 4 because it is using ARC and other technologies.

Comment: The current updated code at the link has bugs in it and can be crashed easily

Comment: Like Ankit Srivastava mentioned before it's easy to break this code example: just copy and paste all item dictionaries in the PlaysAndQuotations.plist (i've tested this with 30 entries in the root dictionary) - Now start the app and open the first play - after that you scroll down until you see an arrow which is pointing down (i think this comes from `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier`) - click that arrow and scroll back to the first play and try to close it -> NSInternalInconsistencyException (iOS 8.4 / iPhone 5s)

Answer (score 25):

I got a nice solution inspired by Apple's [Table View Animations and Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html). I deleted unnecessary parts from Apple's sample and translated it into swift.

I know the answer is quite long, but all the code is necessary. Fortunately, you can just copy and paste most of the code and just need to do a bit modification on step 1 and 3

1.create `SectionHeaderView.swift` and `SectionHeaderView.xib`

```
import UIKit

protocol SectionHeaderViewDelegate {
    func sectionHeaderView(sectionHeaderView: SectionHeaderView, sectionOpened: Int)
    func sectionHeaderView(sectionHeaderView: SectionHeaderView, sectionClosed: Int)
}

class SectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    var section: Int?
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var disclosureButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func toggleOpen() {
        self.toggleOpenWithUserAction(true)
    }
    var delegate: SectionHeaderViewDelegate?
    
    func toggleOpenWithUserAction(userAction: Bool) {
        self.disclosureButton.selected = !self.disclosureButton.selected
        
        if userAction {
            if self.disclosureButton.selected {
                self.delegate?.sectionHeaderView(self, sectionClosed: self.section!)
            } else {
                self.delegate?.sectionHeaderView(self, sectionOpened: self.section!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "toggleOpen")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        // change the button image here, you can also set image via IB.
        self.disclosureButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_up"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        self.disclosureButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_down"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    
}
```

the `SectionHeaderView.xib`(the view with gray background) should look something like this in a tableview(you can customize it according to your needs, of course):
[image]

note:

a) the `toggleOpen` action should be linked to `disclosureButton`

b) the `disclosureButton` and `toggleOpen` action are not necessary. You can delete these 2 things if you don't need the button.

2.create `SectionInfo.swift`

```
import UIKit

class SectionInfo: NSObject {
    var open: Bool = true
    var itemsInSection: NSMutableArray = []
    var sectionTitle: String?
    
    init(itemsInSection: NSMutableArray, sectionTitle: String) {
        self.itemsInSection = itemsInSection
        self.sectionTitle = sectionTitle
    }
}
```

3.in your tableview

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, SectionHeaderViewDelegate  {
    
    let SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = "SectionHeaderViewIdentifier"
    
    var sectionInfoArray: NSMutableArray = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let sectionHeaderNib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "SectionHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.registerNib(sectionHeaderNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: SectionHeaderViewIdentifier)
        
        // you can change section height based on your needs
        self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 30
        
        // You should set up your SectionInfo here
        var firstSection: SectionInfo = SectionInfo(itemsInSection: ["1"], sectionTitle: "firstSection")
        var secondSection: SectionInfo = SectionInfo(itemsInSection: ["2"], sectionTitle: "secondSection"))
        sectionInfoArray.addObjectsFromArray([firstSection, secondSection])
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionInfoArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.sectionInfoArray.count > 0 {
            var sectionInfo: SectionInfo = sectionInfoArray[section] as! SectionInfo
            if sectionInfo.open {
                return sectionInfo.open ? sectionInfo.itemsInSection.count : 0
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeaderView: SectionHeaderView! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(SectionHeaderViewIdentifier) as! SectionHeaderView
        var sectionInfo: SectionInfo = sectionInfoArray[section] as! SectionInfo
        
        sectionHeaderView.titleLabel.text = sectionInfo.sectionTitle
        sectionHeaderView.section = section
        sectionHeaderView.delegate = self
        let backGroundView = UIView()
        // you can customize the background color of the header here
        backGroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.89, green:0.89, blue:0.89, alpha:1)
        sectionHeaderView.backgroundView = backGroundView
        return sectionHeaderView
    }
    
    func sectionHeaderView(sectionHeaderView: SectionHeaderView, sectionOpened: Int) {
        var sectionInfo: SectionInfo = sectionInfoArray[sectionOpened] as! SectionInfo
        var countOfRowsToInsert = sectionInfo.itemsInSection.count
        sectionInfo.open = true
        
        var indexPathToInsert: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        for i in 0..<countOfRowsToInsert {
            indexPathToInsert.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: sectionOpened))
        }
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathToInsert as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: .Top)
    }
    
    func sectionHeaderView(sectionHeaderView: SectionHeaderView, sectionClosed: Int) {
        var sectionInfo: SectionInfo = sectionInfoArray[sectionClosed] as! SectionInfo
        var countOfRowsToDelete = sectionInfo.itemsInSection.count
        sectionInfo.open = false
        if countOfRowsToDelete > 0 {
            var indexPathToDelete: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
            for i in 0..<countOfRowsToDelete {
                indexPathToDelete.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: sectionClosed))
            }
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathToDelete as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: .Top)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for making the effort on this! With a small sample project on github it would be an even better answer

Comment: Thanks for providing detail answer.Example project would be better.

Answer (score 23):

To implement the collapsible table section in iOS, the magic is how to control the number of rows for each section, or we can manage the height of rows for each section.

Also, we need to customize the section header so that we can listen to the tap event from the header area (whether it's a button or the whole header).

How to deal with the header? It's very simple, we extend the UITableViewCell class and make a custom header cell like so:

```
import UIKit

class CollapsibleTableViewHeader: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var toggleButton: UIButton!

}
```

then use the viewForHeaderInSection to hook up the header cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("header") as! CollapsibleTableViewHeader

  header.titleLabel.text = sections[section].name
  header.toggleButton.tag = section
  header.toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CollapsibleTableViewController.toggleCollapse), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

  header.toggleButton.rotate(sections[section].collapsed! ? 0.0 : CGFloat(M_PI_2))

  return header.contentView
}
```

remember we have to return the contentView because this function expects a UIView to be returned.

Now let's deal with the collapsible part, here is the toggle function that toggle the collapsible prop of each section:

```
func toggleCollapse(sender: UIButton) {
  let section = sender.tag
  let collapsed = sections[section].collapsed

  // Toggle collapse
  sections[section].collapsed = !collapsed

  // Reload section
  tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

depends on how you manage the section data, in this case, I have the section data something like this:

```
struct Section {
  var name: String!
  var items: [String]!
  var collapsed: Bool!

  init(name: String, items: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
    self.collapsed = false
  }
}

var sections = [Section]()

sections = [
  Section(name: "Mac", items: ["MacBook", "MacBook Air", "MacBook Pro", "iMac", "Mac Pro", "Mac mini", "Accessories", "OS X El Capitan"]),
  Section(name: "iPad", items: ["iPad Pro", "iPad Air 2", "iPad mini 4", "Accessories"]),
  Section(name: "iPhone", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"])
]
```

at last, what we need to do is based on the collapsible prop of each section, control the number of rows of that section:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return (sections[section].collapsed!) ? 0 : sections[section].items.count
}
```

I have a fully working demo on my Github: https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

[image: demo]

If you want to implement the collapsible sections in a grouped-style table, I have another demo with source code here: https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section-in-grouped-section

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I did my custom header section on a xib file and registered the nib to my Table View Controller. When I delete a section and try to expand/collapse again, I get a fatal error saying index is out of range. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: very nice and clean solution!

Comment: Swift 5:       tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)

Answer (score 10):

I have a better solution that you should add a UIButton into section header and set this button's size equal to section size, but make it hidden by clear background color, after that you are easily to check which section is clicked to expand or collapse

Comment: In my opinion, this solution is better than the accepted answer, because semantically you keep your header as a header and you don't use a fake row to simulate a header. Method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` will be untouched and you will continue to be able to use it for what it really means. Same goes for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: So, you tap the button in the section header, but how are you going to determine which section should be reloaded?

Comment: @Answerbot Hi, It is extremely easy by setting tag for button using the same value with section index.

Comment: Was afraid you would say that. Abuse of the tag property for things like tableView indexes is a poor design choice.

Comment: I've never seen any "great" solutions to the problem, which is why I was hoping you had a different approach. The best answer I've seen is the Apple reference project. Apple subclasses a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and adds a `section` property and defines a `SectionHeaderViewDelegate` which provides the callback to open/close the section.  (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 7):

I ended up just creating a headerView that contained a button ( i saw [Son Nguyen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234877/480415) above after the fact, but heres my code.. it looks like a lot but it's pretty simple):

declare a couple bools for you sections

```
bool customerIsCollapsed = NO;
bool siteIsCollapsed = NO;
```

...code

now in your tableview delegate methods...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tblSearchResults.frame.size.width, 35)];

    UILabel *lblSection = [UILabel new];
    [lblSection setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
    [lblSection setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17]];
    [lblSection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    lblSection.alpha = 0.5;
    if(section == 0)
    {
        if(!customerIsCollapsed)
            [lblSection setText:@"Customers    --touch to show--"];
        else
            [lblSection setText:@"Customers    --touch to hide--"];
    }
    else
    {
        if(!siteIsCollapsed)
            [lblSection setText:@"Sites    --touch to show--"];
        else
            [lblSection setText:@"Sites    --touch to hide--"];    }

    UIButton *btnCollapse = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnCollapse setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tblSearchResults.frame.size.width, 35)];
    [btnCollapse setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btnCollapse addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnCollapse.tag = section;


    [headerView addSubview:lblSection];
    [headerView addSubview:btnCollapse];

    return headerView;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if(section == 0)
    {
        if(customerIsCollapsed)
            return 0;
        else
            return _customerArray.count;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        if(siteIsCollapsed)
            return 0;
        else
        return _siteArray.count;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and finally the function that gets called when you touch one of the section header buttons:

```
- (IBAction)touchedSection:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnSection = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(btnSection.tag == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Touched Customers header");
        if(!customerIsCollapsed)
            customerIsCollapsed = YES;
        else
            customerIsCollapsed = NO;

    }
    else if(btnSection.tag == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Touched Site header");
        if(!siteIsCollapsed)
            siteIsCollapsed = YES;
        else
            siteIsCollapsed = NO;

    }
    [_tblSearchResults reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering, wether the section will collapse and expand animated or without animation. Without animation it will look very bad. how can we add animation to it ?

Comment: @Sam if you use something like `[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` in the collapse/uncollapse method it should animate nicely.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best way i found to create expandable table view cells

.h file

```
  NSMutableIndexSet *expandedSections;
```

.m file

```
if (!expandedSections)
    {
        expandedSections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    }
   UITableView *masterTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,1024,648) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    masterTable.delegate = self;
    masterTable.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:masterTable];
```

Table view delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // if (section>0) return YES;

    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            return 5; // return rows when expanded
        }

        return 1; // only top row showing
    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // first row
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Expandable"; // only top row showing

            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
            {

                UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITableContract"]];
                cell.accessoryView = imView;
            }
            else
            {

                UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITableExpand"]];
                cell.accessoryView = imView;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // all other rows
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"section one";
            }else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"section 2";
            }else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"3";
            }else {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"some other sections";
            }

            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Normal Cell";

    }

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;


            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }


            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i 
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITableExpand"]];
                cell.accessoryView = imView;
            }
            else
            {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITableContract"]];
                cell.accessoryView = imView;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"section :%d,row:%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

}
```

Comment: You should probably flag questions as exact duplicates instead of just spamming the same answer on all of them.

Comment: if a section is already expanded and another section is clicked, it gives error

Comment: hi sir,Selected index hight how to change?heightForRowAtIndexPath how to work with your code?

Comment: hi sir how to navigate to the another view controller on didselected of expanded row?

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the 'button in header' solution, here is a clean and minimalist implementation:

- you keep track of collapsed (or expanded) sections in a property
- you tag the button with the section index
- you set a selected state on that button to change the arrow direction (like △ and ▽)

Here is the code:

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableIndexSet *collapsedSections;
@end

...

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (!self)
        return;
    self.collapsedSections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // if section is collapsed
    if ([self.collapsedSections containsIndex:section])
        return 0;

    // if section is expanded
#warning incomplete implementation
    return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (IBAction)toggleSectionHeader:(UIView *)sender
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    NSInteger section = sender.tag;

    MyTableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (MyTableViewHeaderFooterView *)[self tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];

    if ([self.collapsedSections containsIndex:section])
    {
        // section is collapsed
        headerView.button.selected = YES;
        [self.collapsedSections removeIndex:section];
    }
    else
    {
        // section is expanded
        headerView.button.selected = NO;
        [self.collapsedSections addIndex:section];
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another relatively simple way to solve that problem. By using this method we will not required to alter our cell which is almost always related to data array index, potentially causing mess in our view controller.

First, we add this following properties to our controller class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* collapsedSections;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* sectionViews;
```

`collapsedSections` will save collapsed section numbers.
`sectionViews` will store our custom section view.

Synthesize it:

```
@synthesize collapsedSections;
@synthesize sectionViews;
```

Initialize it:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collapsedSections = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.sectionViews      = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

After that, we must connect our UITableView so it can be accessed from within our view controller class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblMain;
```

Connect it from XIB to view controller using `ctrl + drag` like usually.

Then we create view as custom section header for our table view by implementing this UITableView delegate:

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Create View
    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;

    frame.origin = CGPointZero;

    frame.size.height = 30.f;
    frame.size.width  = tableView.bounds.size.width;

    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    // Add label for title
    NSArray* titles = @[@"Title 1", @"Title 2", @"Title 3"];

    NSString* selectedTitle = [titles objectAtIndex:section];

    CGRect labelFrame = frame;

    labelFrame.size.height = 30.f;
    labelFrame.size.width -= 20.f;
    labelFrame.origin.x += 10.f;

    UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];

    [titleLabel setText:selectedTitle];
    [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [view addSubview:titleLabel];

    // Add touch gesture
    [self attachTapGestureToView:view];

    // Save created view to our class property array
    [self saveSectionView:view inSection:section];

    return view;
}
```

Next, we implement method to save our previously created custom section header in class property:

```
- (void) saveSectionView:(UIView*) view inSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    NSInteger sectionCount = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:[self tblMain]];

    if(section < sectionCount)
    {
        if([[self sectionViews] indexOfObject:view] == NSNotFound)
        {
            [[self sectionViews] addObject:view];
        }
    }
}
```

Add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to our view controller .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Then we create method `attachTapGestureToView:`

```
- (void) attachTapGestureToView:(UIView*) view
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapAction = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];

    [tapAction setDelegate:self];

    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapAction];
}
```

Above method will add tap gesture recognizer to all of section view we created before. Next we should implement `onTap:` selector

```
- (void) onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    // Take view who attach current recognizer
    UIView* sectionView = [gestureRecognizer view]; 

    // [self sectionViews] is Array containing our custom section views
    NSInteger section = [self sectionNumberOfView:sectionView];

    // [self tblMain] is our connected IBOutlet table view
    NSInteger sectionCount = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:[self tblMain]];

    // If section more than section count minus one set at last
    section = section > (sectionCount - 1) ? 2 : section;

    [self toggleCollapseSection:section];
}
```

Above method will invoked when user tap any of our table view section. This method search correct section number based on our `sectionViews` array we created before.

Also, we implement method to get wihch section of header view belongs to.

```
- (NSInteger) sectionNumberOfView:(UIView*) view
{
    UILabel* label = [[view subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSInteger sectionNum = 0;

    for(UIView* sectionView in [self sectionViews])
    {
        UILabel* sectionLabel = [[sectionView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

        //NSLog(@"Section: %d -> %@ vs %@", sectionNum, [label text], [sectionLabel text]);

        if([[label text] isEqualToString:[sectionLabel text]])
        {
            return sectionNum;
        }

        sectionNum++;
    }

    return NSNotFound;
}
```

Next, we must implement method `toggleCollapseSection:`

```
- (void) toggleCollapseSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    if([self isCollapsedSection:section])
    {
        [self removeCollapsedSection:section];
    }
    else
    {
        [self addCollapsedSection:section];
    }

    [[self tblMain] reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

This method will insert/remove section number to our `collapsedSections` array we created before. When a section number inserted to that array, it means that the section should be collapsed and expanded if otherwise.

Next we implement `removeCollapsedSection:`, `addCollapsedSection:section` and `isCollapsedSection:section`

```
- (BOOL)isCollapsedSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    for(NSNumber* existing in [self collapsedSections])
    {
        NSInteger current = [existing integerValue];

        if(current == section)
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)removeCollapsedSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    [[self collapsedSections] removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]];
}

- (void)addCollapsedSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    [[self collapsedSections] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]];
}
```

This three method is just helpers to make us easier in accessing `collapsedSections` array.

Finally, implement this table view delegate so our custom section views looks nice.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.f; // Same as each custom section view height
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a NSDictionary as datasource, this looks like a lot of code, but it's really simple and works very well!
[how looks here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLuwV.png)

I created a enum for the sections

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TableViewSection) {

    TableViewSection0 = 0,
    TableViewSection1,
    TableViewSection2,
    TableViewSectionCount
};
```

sections property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * sectionsDisctionary;
```

A method returning my sections:

```
-(NSArray <NSNumber *> * )sections{

    return @[@(TableViewSection0), @(TableViewSection1), @(TableViewSection2)];
}
```

And then setup my data soruce:

```
-(void)loadAndSetupData{

    self.sectionsDisctionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSArray * sections = [self sections];

    for (NSNumber * section in sections) {

    NSArray * sectionObjects = [self objectsForSection:section.integerValue];

    [self.sectionsDisctionary setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"visible" : @YES, @"objects" : sectionObjects}] forKey:section];
    }
}

-(NSArray *)objectsForSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSArray * objects;

    switch (section) {

        case TableViewSection0:

            objects = @[] // objects for section 0;
            break;

        case TableViewSection1:

            objects = @[] // objects for section 1;
            break;

        case TableViewSection2:

            objects = @[] // objects for section 2;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return objects;
}
```

The next methods, will help you to know when a section is opened, and how to respond to tableview datasource:

Respond the section to datasource:

```
/**
 *  Asks the delegate for a view object to display in the header of the specified section of the table view.
 *
 *  @param tableView The table-view object asking for the view object.
 *  @param section   An index number identifying a section of tableView .
 *
 *  @return A view object to be displayed in the header of section .
 */
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSString * headerName = [self titleForSection:section];

    YourCustomSectionHeaderClass * header = (YourCustomSectionHeaderClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:YourCustomSectionHeaderClassIdentifier];

    [header setTag:section];
    [header addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)]];
    header.title = headerName;
    header.collapsed = [self sectionIsOpened:section];


    return header;
}

/**
 * Asks the data source to return the number of sections in the table view
 *
 * @param An object representing the table view requesting this information.
 * @return The number of sections in tableView.
 */
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    // Return the number of sections.

    return self.sectionsDisctionary.count;
}

/**
 * Tells the data source to return the number of rows in a given section of a table view
 *
 * @param tableView: The table-view object requesting this information.
 * @param section: An index number identifying a section in tableView.
 * @return The number of rows in section.
 */
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    BOOL sectionOpened = [self sectionIsOpened:section];
    return sectionOpened ? [[self objectsForSection:section] count] : 0;
}
```

Tools:

```
/**
 Return the section at the given index

 @param index the index

 @return The section in the given index
 */
-(NSMutableDictionary *)sectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    NSString * asectionKey = [self.sectionsDisctionary.allKeys objectAtIndex:index];

    return [self.sectionsDisctionary objectForKey:asectionKey];
}

/**
 Check if a section is currently opened

 @param section the section to check

 @return YES if is opened
 */
-(BOOL)sectionIsOpened:(NSInteger)section{

    NSDictionary * asection = [self sectionAtIndex:section];
    BOOL sectionOpened = [[asection objectForKey:@"visible"] boolValue];

    return sectionOpened;
}


/**
 Handle the section tap

 @param tap the UITapGestureRecognizer
 */
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap{

    NSInteger index = tap.view.tag;

    [self toggleSection:index];
}
```

Toggle section visibility

```
/**
 Switch the state of the section at the given section number

 @param section the section number
 */
-(void)toggleSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (index >= 0){

        NSMutableDictionary * asection = [self sectionAtIndex:section];

        [asection setObject:@(![self sectionIsOpened:section]) forKey:@"visible"];

        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview-in-ios) answer written in Objective C, I wrote the following for those writing in Swift

The idea is to use sections within the table and set the number of rows in the section to 1 (collapsed) and 3(expanded) when the first row in that section is tapped

The table decides how many rows to draw based on an array of Boolean values

You'll need to create two rows in storyboard and give them the reuse identifiers 'CollapsingRow' and 'GroupHeading'

```
import UIKit

class CollapsingTVC:UITableViewController{

    var sectionVisibilityArray:[Bool]!// Array index corresponds to section in table

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sectionVisibilityArray = [false,false,false]
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return sectionVisibilityArray.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 0
    }

    // numberOfRowsInSection - Get count of entries
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rowsToShow:Int = 0
        if(sectionVisibilityArray[section]){
            rowsToShow = 3 // Or however many rows should be displayed in that section
        }else{
            rowsToShow = 1
        }
        return rowsToShow
    }// numberOfRowsInSection


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            if(sectionVisibilityArray[indexPath.section]){
                sectionVisibilityArray[indexPath.section] = false
            }else{
                sectionVisibilityArray[indexPath.section] = true
            }
            self.tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

    // cellForRowAtIndexPath - Get table cell corresponding to this IndexPath
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell

        if(indexPath.row == 0){
             cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GroupHeading", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        }else{
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CollapsingRow", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        }

        return cell

    }// cellForRowAtIndexPath

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    [mView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 20, 20)];
    [logoView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carat.png"]];
    [mView addSubview:logoView];

    UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];
    [bt setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bt setTag:section];
    [bt.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [bt.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [bt.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [bt setTitle: @"More Info" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(addCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mView addSubview:bt];
    return mView;

}

#pragma mark - Suppose you want to hide/show section 2... then
#pragma mark  add or remove the section on toggle the section header for more info

- (void)addCell:(UIButton *)bt{

    // If section of more information
    if(bt.tag == 2) {

        // Initially more info is close, if more info is open
        if(ifOpen) {
            DLog(@"close More info");

            // Set height of section
            heightOfSection = 0.0f;

            // Reset the parameter that more info is closed now
            ifOpen = NO;
        }else {
            // Set height of section
            heightOfSection = 45.0f;
            // Reset the parameter that more info is closed now
            DLog(@"open more info again");
            ifOpen = YES;
        }
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}// end addCell
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark  What will be the height of the section, Make it dynamic

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        return heightOfSection;
    }else {
        return 45.0f;
    }
```

// vKj

Answer (score 0):

```
This action will happen in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, when you will try to hide or show number of cell in a  section

first of all declare a global variable numberOfSectionInMoreInfo in .h file and in your viewDidLoad set suppose to numberOfSectionInMoreInfo = 4.

Now use following logic: 


 // More info link
        if(row == 3) {

            /*Logic: We are trying to hide/show the number of row into more information section */

            NSString *log= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number of section in more %i",numberOfSectionInMoreInfo];

            [objSpineCustomProtocol showAlertMessage:log];

            // Check if the number of rows are open or close in view
            if(numberOfSectionInMoreInfo > 4) {

                // close the more info toggle
                numberOfSectionInMoreInfo = 4;

            }else {

                // Open more info toggle
                numberOfSectionInMoreInfo = 9;

            }

            //reload this section
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

//vKj

Comment: Why two answers? It doesn't seem you have provided two different solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code for animating an expand/collapse action using a table view section header is provided by Apple at [Table View Animations and Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html).

The key to this approach is to implement

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

and return a custom UIView which includes a button (typically the same size as the header view itself). By subclassing UIView and using that for the header view (as this sample does), you can easily store additional data such as the section number.

Answer (score 0):

**I have done the same thing using multiple sections .**

```
class SCTierBenefitsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var tblTierBenefits: UITableView!
    private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
    private var isSelected:Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblTierBenefits.register(UINib(nibName:"TierBenefitsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"TierBenefitsTableViewCell")
        tblTierBenefits.register(UINib(nibName:"TierBenefitsDetailsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"TierBenefitsDetailsCell")

        tblTierBenefits.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        tblTierBenefits.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
        tblTierBenefits.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}

extension SCTierBenefitsViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 7
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (isSelected && section == selectedIndexPath?.section) ? 2 : 1 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return  0.01
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell:TierBenefitsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TierBenefitsTableViewCell")! as! TierBenefitsTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell

        case 1:
            let cell:TierBenefitsDetailsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TierBenefitsDetailsCell")! as! TierBenefitsDetailsCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell

        default:
            break
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

extension SCTierBenefitsViewController : UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            if let _selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath ,selectedIndexPath?.section == indexPath.section {
                tblTierBenefits.beginUpdates()
                expandCollapse(indexPath: _selectedIndexPath, isExpand: false)
                selectedIndexPath = nil
            }
            else{
                tblTierBenefits.beginUpdates()
                if selectedIndexPath != nil {
                    tblTierBenefits.reloadSections([(selectedIndexPath?.section)!], with: .none)
                }
                expandCollapse(indexPath: indexPath, isExpand: true)
            }
        }
    }

    private func  expandCollapse(indexPath: IndexPath?,isExpand: Bool){
        isSelected = isExpand
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tblTierBenefits.reloadSections([(indexPath?.section)!], with: .none)
        tblTierBenefits.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this solution for completeness and showing how to work with section headers.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var headerButtons: [UIButton]!
    var sections = [true, true, true]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        let section0Button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        section0Button.setTitle("Section 0", for: .normal)
        section0Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(section0Tapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        let section1Button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        section1Button.setTitle("Section 1", for: .normal)
        section1Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(section1Tapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        let section2Button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        section2Button.setTitle("Section 2", for: .normal)
        section2Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(section2Tapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        headerButtons = [UIButton]()
        headerButtons.append(section0Button)
        headerButtons.append(section1Button)
        headerButtons.append(section2Button)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section] ? 3 : 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellReuseId = "cellReuseId"
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellReuseId)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section): \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return headerButtons[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    @objc func section0Tapped() {
        sections[0] = !sections[0]
        tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .fade)
    }

    @objc func section1Tapped() {
        sections[1] = !sections[1]
        tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .fade)
    }

    @objc func section2Tapped() {
        sections[2] = !sections[2]
        tableView.reloadSections([2], with: .fade)
    }

}
```

Link to gist: https://gist.github.com/pawelkijowskizimperium/fe1e8511a7932a0d40486a2669316d2c

Answer (score 0):

in support to @jean.timex solution, use below code if you want to open one section at any time. create a variable like: var expandedSection = -1;

```
func toggleSection(_ header: CollapsibleTableViewHeader, section: Int) {
    let collapsed = !sections[section].collapsed
    // Toggle collapse
    sections[section].collapsed = collapsed
    header.setCollapsed(collapsed)
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
    if (expandedSection >= 0 && expandedSection != section){
        sections[expandedSection].collapsed = true
        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: expandedSection) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
    }
    expandedSection = section;
}
```