# How to have topics and subtopics in single tableviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

I am just thinking to create like below using tableview, but i am not sure how to make it work

```
 Sports (If it get touched it expands the subtopics) 
    Cricket (When it get Touched it push to next view controller)
    Football
    VolleyBall
 Bike (If it get touched it expands the subtopics)
    HeroHonda (When it get Touched it push to next view controller)
    Kawasaki
    Yamaha
```

The number of topics and subtopics are known.

Is it possible to do like what i am expecting?
If it cannot be possible with the table view then what is the other way of doing this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please further elaborate on what *exactly* you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Create two `UITableViewCell` subclasses for the topic and subtopic, and use them accordingly (with just one section). Then insert/delete rows when the topics are tapped (and of course, update your data source before reloading the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941766/869455) You need to reload section to expand and collapse the subtopics.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need an expansion effect, I reccomend that you use some open-source solution such as [VPPDropDown](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown) , or even [MPFoldTransition](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition.git).

The simpler solution would be to just use UITableViewSections for categories and cells for items, e.g.

```
Section 0 : Sports
  - Row 0 : Cricket
  - Row 1 : Football

Section 1 : Bike
  - Row 0 : Yamaha
  - Row 1 : Kawasaki
```