# Collapse sections in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am doing an application form in my app and I want to make something creative, so I thought of having the form components in sections (like the following images), and do a collapse and expand affect on them.

[image: collapsed]
[image: expanded]

Is there is any class or something which could help me implementing this or I have to do it manually?

Comment: I added the images for you :)

Comment: What is the base `UIView` subclass you are using?  If it's `UITableView` then tag your question with it and change "Objective-C" to "table view" in your title.

Comment: 1) http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview

Answer (score 3):

I used to take advantage of a UITableView and the methods

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths 
  withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

and

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths 
  withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

to simulate and expand/collapse behaviour.

Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

I've used then selectable section headers (either via UIButton or gesture recognizers) to let the user expand/collapse.

There are also a lot of tutorials out there that are quite explanatory, using different techniques:

- [Collapsable Table View for iOS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Collapsable-Table-View-for-iOS)
- [Expandable/Collapsible Table For iOS](http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/)

Finally you can take a look to this control that should provide the functionality that you are searching for:

[UIExpandableTableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView)