# Show/hide tableviewCells when click on each tableview cell iOS (Accordion UITableView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a tableview that contains categories and subcategories. When loading the tableview  it should show categories. When the user click on each category cell it should expand and show subcategories. When the user again click on the particular cell it should hide the subcategory list. The subcategory list count should be different for different category cells. And the subcategory list should be **User Interaction Enabled**.

I've read the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) but it didn't helped much. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: These will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview
https://github.com/iSofTom/STCollapseTableView

Comment: Thanks aBilal.. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

make use of

```
[self.tableView insertrowsatindexpaths:@[...] withRowAnimation:...];
```

and

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[...] withRowAnimation:...];
```

inside your tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of methods but nothing worked well. Last I have found a sample project in Github. The code is  [here](https://github.com/ajkoshy7/SubTable) for anyone for future reference. Thanks