# TableView Index with Button Title

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton, tableview

I am having two table views TableView1, TableView2. TableView1  contains a list of buttons when I click on any button TableView2 will appear with a list of numbers.

Now when I select any number, that number needs to be displayed in clicked button.

Can anyone help me out with some logic from this as I am new to IOS?

```
btn_select=[[UIButton alloc]init];
        btn_select.frame=CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-245,10,55, 27);
        btn_select.layer.cornerRadius=5;
        btn_select.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
        [btn_select addTarget:self action:@selector(NumberButtonclicke:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn_select.tag=indexPath.row;
        [btn_select.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [btn_select setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:btn_select];

-(void)NumberButtonclicke:(UIButton *)Sender
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)NumberButtonclicke:(UIButton *)Sender
{
   CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView: Yourtableview];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [Yourtableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
   NSString *str = [Yourarary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // Your Number list
   NSLog(@"Number is ---%@", str)

 }
```

Comment: number.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row+1]; i dont have arry to take .

Comment: If no array . Your code It  will give as row number which row you will select

Comment: when i click on did select row at indexpath in number tableview then the click button text need to change to clicked index number

Comment: [Your button setTitle:number.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: all buttons are changing i have already tried this i need only clickd button to change

Comment: [sender setTitle:number.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: [sender setTitle:number.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];  how can write this in did select row cell

Answer (score 0):

May be you need only one tableView with collapse and expand Section on click.

Here is the duplicate answer :[Expand/collapse section in UITableView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview-in-ios)

On Selection of the row , changed the Section Header while reload the table