# Xamarin.iOS dynamically ScrollView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, scrollview

I really need your help.
I'm new at developing Xamarin.iOS apps and now I'm totally stuck. 
I cannot get the hang of how to implement a dynamic ScrollView in iOS, it was fairly easy to implement on Android.

So what I'm trying to implement is a view that contains mostly text (that will be quite long, hence the scrolling, but also two buttons.

**[Here is a gif in Android showing what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG0jF.gif)**

The view is like this:

`Header
Long text
Copyright button
 -- Copyright text 
Terms of usage button
 -- Terms of usage text`

I have struggled with the scrolling so long and I really need your help.
All of the text properties are getting bound to the view by binding with MvvmCross so the view can't be with hard-coded heights and widths, it needs to adjust properly.

**Can somebody please show me with a sample project how to implement it?**

**The view needs to be in a .xib view (because of MvvmCross) and it cannot contain a UIViewcontroller.**

**So the solution needs to be in a simple UIView**

I'm working on a Windows, with Visual Studio 2015 enterprise, and I cannot use a Mac (and Xcode) other than to compile my code with.

What I've tried is a solution like this:

```
UIView called "MyRootview"
-- UIScrollView called "MyScrollView"
-- -- UIView called "MyContentView"
```

**Can you please help me?**

Comment: You can update height constraint programmatically

Comment: @Taier how would you do that? Can you explain? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FluentLayout instead. Very easy.

https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

Use a TableView instead of ScrollView. Make the header row 1, long text row 2, button 1 and it's text row 3 and button 4 and it's text row 4.

Give row height for the last 2 rows so that you only see the button and on button click increase the row height and reload the table section.

Method 2:

If you keep wanna using ScrollView, put the button data in a label and give it a height of 0 (and number of lines 1) to hide it and on button click remove the height constraint and set the number of lines to 0 (max).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give it a try. Do you have any example code to look at?

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941766/2974780


And this:
https://github.com/stvansolano/crossPlatformDevelopment/tree/master/FeaturedApps/ToDoApp/CrossPlatformApp/CrossPlatformApp/CustomControls/AccordionView