# Create collapsible disclosure-style views in iOS (Etsy app as example)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

I am wondering what people think the best way to create collapsible disclosure views would be for iOS similar to the example below in Etsy's app.
[image: Etsy app displaying examples of collapsible views]
More specifically I would like to have the views have input fields related to the headers, and I'm not sure whether or not table views and cells (which seem to commonly be suggested for collapsible sections) are able to handle that. (Though if so, feel free to link me to resources!)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview-in-ios

Comment: check working Code - https://github.com/RockinGarg/Expandable-TableView-.git

Comment: Would something like the above example be a proper use of the table view? (Asking since I haven't figured out if this has been what the community has decided on in terms of best practices.)