# How to implement a collapsing header?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I tried to implement a collapsing UITableView Header but right now I am not getting any further. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvZ3t.jpg) is my storyboard. I tried to use the **scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)** delegate method but the position is not changing at all while scrolling in the table view which is embedded in the container. The **heightConstraint** is the height of my container header view.
[Here](https://pastebin.com/8c3kSMAw) is the full source code for my class. I appreciate any help! Sitting on this problem for some time now.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.maxHeaderHeight
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let absoluteTop: CGFloat = 0
    let absoluteBottom: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    let scrollDiff = scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.previousScrollOffset
    let isScrollingDown = scrollDiff > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y > absoluteTop
    let isScrollingUp = scrollDiff < 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < absoluteBottom

    var newHeight = self.heightConstraint.constant
    if isScrollingDown {
        newHeight = max(self.minHeaderHeight, self.heightConstraint.constant - abs(scrollDiff))
    } else if isScrollingUp {
        newHeight = min(self.maxHeaderHeight, self.heightConstraint.constant + abs(scrollDiff))
    }

    if newHeight != self.heightConstraint.constant {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = newHeight
    }

    self.previousScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

While scrolling up the header container should disappear/change its location.

Comment: Did you check this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview-in-ios ?
I think it would be easier for you to achieve it with tableView check this link https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0

Comment: Thanks for the links.. I have to use a container view for the navigation. There is no way around it. I achieved it with a table view tho :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can handle the `headerView` `height` with `tableView` `scrolling`,

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    let maxHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 115.0

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
            //Scrolled to bottom
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = 0.0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.lastContentOffset || scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) && (self.heightConstraint.constant != self.maxHeaderHeight)  {
            //Scrolling up, scrolled to top
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = self.maxHeaderHeight
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset) && self.heightConstraint.constant != 0.0 {
            //Scrolling down
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = 0.0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
}
```

In the above code `headerView` will,

1. **collapse** when the `tableView` is `scrolled up`
2. **expand** when the `tableView` is `scrolled down`

Let me know in case you still face any issues.

Comment: I made a [gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/ios-swift-JNs7vdoSrJnLZfFP2i) to show the problem I am facing. Im not using a table view in the first place. I use a container view to navigate and then I add a table view into it.

Comment: is it a problem to use a container view here instead of a table view?

Comment: The code will work for any `scrollView` and not just the `tableView`.

Comment: Is your `containerView` scrolling?

Comment: Do I have to add a Scroll View element into my hierarchy?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise how will you be able to scroll your view?

Comment: I see. But do I have to replace my whole view or do I only have to add my container view into the scroll view. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/ZzU2qIu) is my storyboard.

Comment: How do I have to constraint the scroll view and the container view? It looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/gmMpx2Q)

Comment: I am having trouble with the scroll view..Do I have to place it right under the header which I want to collapse?

Comment: right now my scroll view is under my stack view where my container view was.. and my container view is inside it but my header is not collapsing right now